# Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "table"

Tags: r, dplyr

This is the code I want to run:

```
njnew <- nj %>%
   summary(num.totalbirths=sum(births20142015)) %>%
    mutate(percent.birth=births20142015/num.totalbirths)
```

then I get this response

```
>  njnew <- nj %>%
+    summary(num.totalbirths=sum(births20142015)) %>%
+     mutate(percent.birth=births20142015/num.totalbirths)
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "table"
```

I want to say that I have been having problem installing packages.When I install some packages I get this:

```
Do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation? (Yes/no/cancel) no
```

I tried "no" and that seemed to let me install it.

Do you know why I am getting this error messages? could you kindly provide a potential solution?

Comment: 1) You are asking 2 questions, please ask just one at a time. 2) It's probaly `summarise` you want, not `summary`. 3) if the package needs compilation you should answer "yes" but that is operating system dependent. Are you on Windows? If so, you can install CRAN packages without compilation, there are binary versions on CRAN.

Comment: you are right, summarise worked.Thank you. I am using a MAC, is there anything I need to do for that?

Comment: Probably not, I'm not a Mac user but problems when installing packages should be solved on a case by case basis. Try it out then if there is a problem post a question with the code you have tried and the error message.